# Laptop on overhead bin vs. turbulence

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items

If a laptop is on the overhead bin and some moderate/strong turbulence occurs, it is possible that the laptop "jumps" several centimeters.

How to protect the laptop from this?

Comment: Of course it can jump. You can put some clothes around it (jacket, sweater etc.) so it stays in place. But if you have it in a laptop bag with sufficient padding, it is probably safe from being destroyed.

Comment: I would be more worried about it getting damaged from contact with other people's hard shell cases. Unless you are sat in international First/Business, it's likely the overhead is going to be pretty rammed with other people's stuff.

Comment: Make sure it is powered off or hibernated.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't put it "naked" in the overhead bin, any laptop bag will suffice.